# Using WPF class in a web application, problem with hosting permission

Tags: c#, wpf, web, permissions, shared-hosting

I'm developing a DLL that uses WPF classes to make image manipulation. 
It works fine in my local environment, but when I try to use it in an hosted web site I retrieve this error:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.MediaPermission, WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' failed.
```

exactly when I try to call the EndInit() of a BitmapImage object:

```
BitmapImage originalImage = new BitmapImage();
originalImage.BeginInit();
originalImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
originalImage.UriSource = new Uri(physical_imagepath);
originalImage.EndInit();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What host are you using? 1and1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your host to change the permissions.

If they refuse, switch to a better webhost.

Comment: nope, my webhost says that in shared hosting there's no way to have a dll to full trust. If you know a shared hosting service that can do this, plese let me know! thanks!

Comment: I'm using LFC shared hosting, which is full trust.

Comment: I'm using Aruba, but now I want to check out this LFC, thanks for the answer